# Highcharts -- Getting categories from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to get data from my mysql into Highcharts bar graph. I have the data from mysql that includes a port number and average bytes per port. Here is what I have for my php query and html page. The data (average bytes) shows up on the graph just fine. I can't get the categories (port) data to display.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","kdkdkdk") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("silk", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT dstPortNum,avgByte FROM statistic_avgbytesport ORDER BY avgByte DESC LIMIT 10;");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
#print json_encode($rows[0][0], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And my html page to display the graph.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Pie Chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'avgbytes'                  
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Average Bytes Per Port'
                },

                pane: {
                    size:'80%'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'PORTS'
                    },
                    categories: []
                },

                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Bytes'
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    name: 'Average Bytes',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

            $.getJSON("averageBytesPerPort.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });



        });   
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="avgbytes" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show the json ('console.log(json)' should do)?  Does removing the 'categories: []' line help at all?

Comment: Removing categories[] does change the graph a bit but it is still not what I am looking for. I see an automatic number count from 0 to 60k and not the individual port numbers in the query.

Comment: You should create a jsFiddle for this. You'll need to fudge a couple things since that getJSON() call won't work but at least we'll be able to see what you are seeing... and tweak it. It can also force you to examine the JSON being returned to make sure it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$.getJSON("averageBytesPerPort.php", function(json) {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'avgbytes'                  
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Average Bytes Per Port'
        },

        pane: {
            size:'80%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'PORTS'
            },
            categories: data.categories
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Bytes'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            name: 'Average Bytes',
            data: data
        }]
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how the hell on earth your data is shown , you have not put the $conn as the second parameter of the 
 mysql_query();
it should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT dstPortNum,avgByte FROM statistic_avgbytesport ORDER BY avgByte DESC LIMIT 10;",$conn);
```